# How to activate Java Plug in in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Strangely in Add ons section of Firefox, I could not see the Java add on (activate/de-activate).

So, How to enable Java ? (given I activated Brower in Java Configuration).

Thanks

Comment: As written, this does not appear to be a programming specific question.  As such: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).

Answer (score -1):

Java 64bits does not work with Firefox.
Also Firefox 64bits does not work with Java.

1) Need to Install Firefox 32bits
2) Need to install Java X86 586 (= 32bits)

all in separate folder.
Also Please close Firefox when installing Java.